# Restoring model in tensorflow hangs

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, tensorflow, tensor2tensor

I have a model of moderate complexity written in tensorflow using tensor2tensor. (It uses an RNN, if that is relevant.) The model saves to disk relatively quickly (~30 seconds), but when I try to restore it, it hangs, seemingly forever. I've given it half an hour and it never finishes.

Interestingly, it is able to restore a model relatively efficiently when the job first starts. When I examine the running processes using top, the successful loading takes up 300% cpu, while the unsuccessful loading takes up about 30% cpu, and that only sporadically.

I have tried to make sure that I am using the C++ implementation of protobuf, as that is one possible cause of slow loads. Not entirely sure how to verify that I am using it, however.

Comment: Hard to say anything without a way to reproduce. Can you put one together? If not, how many ops are in the graph (`len(tf.get_default_graph().get_operations())`), and how many/how large are the variables? I'd also try saving/restoring just a checkpoint (no graph) and then just a GraphDef (no variables) to figure out which of those is the issue.

Comment: @forefinger Did u figure this thing out ? I am facing the same issue with Tensorflow Estimator while it tries to restore model for Evaluation

Comment: I am facing this issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: Same issue here. Any news?